# Trying to remember an old movie where American family's crops will not grow & UFO visit

Tags: story-identification, movie, moon

I think this is going to be a hard one to discover, but I am hoping that someone will be able to help.

From what I remember, the movie takes place in a small town in Central America, and the family's crops will not grow. There is some importance of the moon and the main character, maybe some relation to the harvest. Later on the family gets other towns people to help them dig a hole in their backyard where something is discovered. Shortly after they are visited by aliens in a large UFO. I can't really remember much else from the movie. Part of me wants to say their was a native man who was a close friend to the family and played a role with the main character who was either an older child or young adult.

It's probably been somewhere between 15-20 years since I have seen this movie.

Answer (score 3):

[Riddler's Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0169177/)

I've been looking for this movie too. 90% sure this is it.

Synopsis from IMDB submitted by John Sacksteder:

> An Indiana single mother and her wheelchair bound son live on a farm
>   that has not produced crops for years. Suddenly the land becomes
>   fertile and blossoms, but so do the neighbors imaginations. In fact,
>   the reason for the sudden growth turns out to be extra-terrestrial.